# Customizing legend with concatenated fields on QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, legend

I prepared a map with a custom legend on QGIS 3.8.1, combining a classification of several concatenated fields. However, when creating the layout compouser and including the legend, the descriptive text of the legend did not keep the same line numbers.

What can be done to make legend able to keep the same number of lines defined in the layer?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could simply limit the width of the legend.

Comment: if I limit the caption the text is truncated.

Comment: Set a character at which to break the text, then add the character where you need it.

Comment: I tried to do that. It works, but it doesn't look good because the right margin is misaligned.

Comment: If looks is what you are going after, you shouldn't have a slab of text in the legend in the first place.